# Use type of a variable as a template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, types, c++14, c++17

I did the following:

```
long long int x = 0;
int digits_of_x = std::numeric_limits<long long int>::digits;
```

And it works fine. However this can easily introduce an error if someone changes the type of `x`. So I would prefer to do it like this:

```
long long int x = 0;
int digits_of_x = std::numeric_limits<typeof(x)>::digits;
```

I found the GCC extension `typeof()` but I want to use some standard function (up to C++17). Is there such a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `decltype`, not `typeof`. Available since C++11:

```
long long int x = 0;
int digits_of_x = std::numeric_limits<decltype(x)>::digits;
```